# Setting different background color for icon of Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

Let's say i have a Jbutton where it has both ImageIcon and text, is it possible to set background color to icon filling it's buttons width?

[image: Jbutton with text and icon]

Comment: Change the background of the icon itself - but it the image will need to be as wide or wider then the text

Comment: I guess I will have to do that.

Comment: BTW '2 egg n biscuit' is not a very good descriptor for a 'hamburger' ..

Comment: Yeah, i will have to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting the button's background and using an icon with transparent background:

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Sweety");
    URL url = new URL("https://findicons.com/files/icons/345/summer/128/cake.png");
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(url));
    button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

[image]

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood it. I have bunch of png images and i have to set seperate  background color for the image.